# Links to Network Shares not opening in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, windows-explorer, microsoft-office, office365

When clicking a shared network file path (\\server-1\) from an email message in Outlook, there are 3 dots that go across the top of the message window like Outlook is thinking about opening the link but never does. Sometimes, 3 or 4 hours later a message will pop up "unable to find the file" or something like that. I have seen this issue before with web links but have been able to resolve that by resetting the web browser.

This happens on some PCs but not all. Updating and/or reinstalling Office365 does not seem to be the fix. I have also reset file explorer.

What causes this? How can I fix it?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Does this issue occur in web mail?

And if your copy the Network shared path and paste it in file explorer directly, can you access to the shared folder successfully?

> This happens on some PCs but not all

Do you mean that some users can open it, but some others cannot? If so, please check the two users' computer and check if there're any differences.

> I have seen this issue before with web links but have been able to resolve that by resetting the web browser.

Do you mean that the issue can be resolved by resetting the web browser? If so, in order to further confirm the issue is related to the web browser, it's suggested that you could change the default browser to check if the issue still exists.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.